# Plugin for Opera. DOM-tree modification

Tags: dom, plugins, opera, opera-extension

I want to create a plugin for opera that modifies tha DOM-tree after the page have been loaded. Does opera have an appropriate plugin API?

Answer (score 1):

Opera now has an extension API. Here's a link to a documentation entry point: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-extensions-hello-world

Answer (score 0):

Opera supports the [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) plugin API (whic powers flash, java, etc), but I suspect you are referring to an extension API like Firefox, Chrome, and Safari have. Opera does not have a comparable extension API.

**Edit by Hallvord: this answer is outdated. While correct at the time, Opera has now developed extensions support.**